# How can I get html canvas objects to follow/resize with one another?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm creating an interactive in canvas where a user can resize a cube using sliders in order to see changes in volume. I need the cube to look like a "package." I've added a "label" to the cube on just one face. How can I get this "label" to resize/move around with the cube when the user resizes it?

The "label"function is what is placing it on the top face of the cube, but when you resize the cube in certain ways using the slider, namely the height, the "label" doesn't resize/move around with the cube properly. Is this a matter of capturing the current x and y points and having the "label's" x and y points follow that?

```
function label(x, y, wx, wy, h) {
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.moveTo(x, y - h * 0.5);
           ctx.lineTo(x - wx, y - h - wx * 0.5);
           ctx.lineTo(x - wx + wy, y - h - (wx * 0.5 + wy * 0.5));
           ctx.lineTo(x + wy, y - h - wy * 0.5);
           ctx.closePath();
           ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
           ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
           ctx.stroke();
           ctx.fill();
       }
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/VillainousGamgee/pen/XvzGZq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you multiply the height input for the label by zero, which may cause this issue. It will not matter what the slider changes the height to, since it will always be multiplied by zero. I edited the code a little with that in mind. Here are the edits:

```
label(
    175,
    100 + yaxis.value / 1.1,
    Number(xaxis.value) * 0.75,
    Number(yaxis.value) * 0.85,
    Number(zaxis.value) * 1.5 - 73,
    'white'
);

function label(x, y, wx, wy, h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y - h);
    ctx.lineTo(x - wx, y - h - wx * 0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(x - wx + wy, y - h - (wx * 0.5 + wy * 0.5));
    ctx.lineTo(x + wy, y - h - wy * 0.5);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

This code seems to fix the height issue.